# Dynamically Hiding Columns Based On Cell Values

Tags: excel, vba, show-hide

I've got a worksheet with a range of cells (B15:BL15) with formulas in them returning either "Show" or "Hide". The values change when I make a selection from a form control (not ActiveX) combo box and I assigned the below macro to the combo box. The macro is supposed to show or hide the column based on the cell values.

The first time I make a selection all of the columns end up hidden regardless of the values in the cells. When I select it again, the code works fine (i.e. I select Option A and all columns in range are hidden. I choose Option B and then go back to Option A and the correct columns are now showing and hiding.). Anything I'm missing here?

```
Option Explicit

Sub ShowHide()

Cells.Columns.EntireColumn.Hidden = False    ' Added to unhide all of the columns first.

Dim c As Range

For Each c In Range("B15:BL15").Cells        ' Range of cells containing the formulas

With c
    If .Value = "Hide" Then
       .EntireColumn.Hidden = True
    Else
        .EntireColumn.Hidden = False
    End If

End With

Next c

End Sub
```

Any help is greatly appreciatd!

Comment: What does option A / B do to trigger the ShowHide()?  I tested the code and it seems to work fine as intended.

Comment: I'm afraid your active sheet is not the one you intend to process. Try to define your sheet according to its name and run the code again. The code is simple and must do what is obvious it should do... Run `Debug.Print ActivePage.Name` and maybe you will have a surprise...

Comment: Combo box (on sheet 1) output feeds into a cubeset formula in another sheet (sheet 2). That set is then referenced by cuberankedmember formulas in in sheet 1. If that formula returns a blank, the formula in the range will return "Hide". If not, it will return "Show".

Example: I select Fruit from the combo box (sheet 1) and a set is created in sheet 2 which pulls in Apples, Oranges, Bananas. Columns A - E in sheet 1 have the cuberankedmember formulas and A - C will have Apples, Oranges, and Bananas in them. D & E are blank. A - C will be "show" and D & E will be "hide"

Comment: What does "I assigned the below macro to the combo box" mean? Is this procedure called by a `combo_Change` event? If your code works on the appropriate sheet and the necessary reference values exist on row 15, the code must run as expected.

Comment: Hi @FaneDuru - Sorry for the edit. It didn't work. I created the form control combo box and when you right click it you have the option to "Assign Macro" so I assigned the ShowHude sub to it. I didn't do a combo_change event.

Comment: @FaneDuru `Debug.Print ActiveSheet.Name` Returned Sheet2, which is correct.

Comment: Doing what you explained you did, you replaced the Combo_Change event with this Procedure. But in this way you are using it like an ordinary button. Now I suppose that you create a Form Control Combo Box. But, if you did  not use the Combo_Change event to do something in its code according to its selected item, how does it "feeds into a cubeset formula in another sheet (sheet 2)"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this helps someone!

The issue was being caused by the code running prior to all calculations finishing and updating the range. During the calc, the cells in the range briefly defaulted to "hide" which triggered the column to be hidden.

I found `Application.CalculateUntilAsyncQueriesDone` which forced the code to run after all calculations finished and the range was updated. Revised code below:

```
Sub ShowHide()

Dim c As Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.CalculateUntilAsyncQueriesDone

For c = 2 To 64
    If Cells(16, c).Value = "Hide" Then
        Columns(c).Hidden = True
    Else
        Columns(c).Hidden = False
    End If
Next c
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

**Note:** I saw multiple threads using and IF statement and then `Application.CalculationState = xlDone` but that didn't work. If anyone knows why I'd love to understand.